# NSNumber=0 in mutable array

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, null, nsnumber

If I store an `NSNumber` that is equal to 0 in an `NSMutableArray` will that be interpreted as `nil` and cause issues with the count method?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out. I know the answers below are right. But if you've seen this with your own eyes it is unbelievable that storing the NSNumber and then creating an NSArray holding that value cuts the array in half at run time. never would I imagine this to be the case but that's exactly what the runtime did.

Comment: Answers below are right. IDE messed up and didn't refresh watched values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you have to differentiate between the object id itself and the contents. The contents of an `NSNumber` set to 0 may well be zero but the *id* for said object is actually a real address.

For example, the object id `0x2222` may look like this in memory (very simplified):

```
           +--------+
0x2222 --> | 0x0000 |
           +--------+
```

You can see the the object id is *not* zero but a real value. The *contents* of the object are zero but that's not relevant to the object id.

The things that goes in the mutable array are the id values for objects, not the contents of those objects.

Answer (score 4):

It will increment the count of the array.
 `[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]`
 is an object and is not nil.

Furthermore, you cannot add nil to an array

```
[mutableArray addObject:anObject];
```

raises an NSInvalidArgumentException if anObject is nil.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *a = [NSMutableArray array];
[a addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
NSLog(@"count: %d", a.count);
```